# Starting and stopping node app from inside Electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to be able to start and stop another node.js application from inside of my electron app.

I have done the following so far which is working to start the node at from bot.js when I run `npm start` to spin up the electron app:

In main.js:

```
var bot = require('./Bot/bot')
, server = require("./server");
```

And in server.js:

```
require("http").createServer(function (req, res) {
res.end("Hello from server started by Electron app!");
}).listen(9000)
```

Now if I wanted to stop the application at bot.js from inside the electron app (or start it again), from something like a button click, I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Server.close()` I think is what you're looking for. 
`.listen()` returns an `http.Server` instance, which this method can be called on:

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.end("Hello from server started by Electron app!");
}).listen(9000);

// To Close:
server.close();
```

You can then call server.listen() again to reopen the connection.  Note that if the server is already open when you try to listen or not listening and you try to close it. 
See the [Server.close() documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_close_callback) for more info!

Comment: The server seems to run even if I don't add .listen() to the end of the createServer method, and even if I manually call .close(). Any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify, the server is still responding to requests after closing? It's normal for it to remain 'running' in the sense that the process is still active, but I don't think it should respond to requests so that may be another problem

Comment: Oh actually since you're not specifying a timeout, the server will continue operating on any existing connections that have been made (but won't open any new ones) after closing it. (ie if you connect clientA to the server and then close the server, clientA will be able to continue connecting, but clientB won't be able to establish a new connection) If you want to change this you can set a timeout on the server via [`server.setTimeout()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback) so that all clients will have to make a new connection after x amount of time

Comment: Thanks for the follow up help. I ended up using a child process to run the other node app using: `var fork = require('child_process').fork;
var child = fork('./Bot/bot');` and then killing it with: `child.kill('SIGINT');`. I think the problem with createServer() is it's on the same thread as the main Electron app process so it can't be killed independently.